# Hibernate Many to Many mapping Insert after Select on Child

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have many to many mapping table client_platform. I want to force hibernate to select platform_id from Platform table and not run insert on platform table.

Client:

```
@Id
@Column(
        name = "client_id",
        columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)"
)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "client_name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}
)
@JoinTable(
        name = "client_platforms",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "client_id",
                updatable = false,
                nullable = false
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "platform_id",
                updatable = false,
                nullable = false
        )
)
private Set<Platform> platforms;
```

Platform:

```
@ManyToMany(
        mappedBy = "platforms",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}
)
private Set<Client> clients;
```

When I insert Client it inserts into Platform and client_platform join table

How can I change the JPA annotation to force hibernate to do a select on platform before inserts into platform and client_platform table

Comment: why do you need a select first?

Comment: I don't want to manage Platform inserts through Client entity. Platform is maintained through its own API and Entity class.

The way I solve it right now is doing a select on the passed platform_id but I wanted to see if there is a better way of handling this through JPA mappings